# docker private registry on our own domain getting i/o timeout error

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

Can anybody help in this below error while running docker push command to setup docker private registry with own domain

```
# docker push docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl:5000/centos
```

> The push refers to a repository [docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl:5000/centos]
>   Put http://docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl:5000/v1/repositories/centos/: dial
>   tcp 34.231.229.79:5000: i/o timeout

**DNS entry**

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
`#nameserver 172.31.0.2
`#search ec2.internal

root@ip-172-31-68-135:~# cat /etc/docker/daemon.json {    "insecure-registries" : [ "docker-reg.sogeti-aws.nl:5000" ] }
```

Docker already restarted but issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

I would believe that is a firewall issue. Are you sure that port 5000 is available and reachable?

Comment: yes it is my all configuration is well but SG in aws in not allowd 5000 , 80 and 443 thanks a lot its working now